# how does my-pane directive's scope get access to selected property in this example

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In [this official example](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), in section "Creating Directives that Communicate", in file my-pane.html, `ng-show='selected'` is used for determining whether the content is to be hidden or not.

**My question is how does my-pane directive get access to `selected` property?**

The way I see it, the scope of my-pane is limited to title property only. `selected` property is visible only in the scope of my-tabs directive.

The plunker link for the example in question is there in the example itself.

Answer (score 0):

In the `link` function of the my-pane directive there's a call to addPane: `tabsCtrl.addPane(scope)`. This adds the directive's scope as a "pane" to the panes array of `tabsCtrl`. The `select` function in that controller sets `pane.selected` - that's how you get the `selected` property on the pane's scope.

Comment: The my-tabs directive exposes an api to add panes. The my-pane directive used that api. So I think that once the function (tabsCtrl.addPane) is called, my-pane has nothing to do with what happens inside that function. addPane function might even discard the arguments of that function. The $scope in add function refers to scope of my-tabs directive. So whatever changes happen, will happen in that scope. Also the scope of my-tabs has selected property for each pane. I confirmed this by ng-inspector tool.

Comment: I don't know why you're talking about what `addPane` "might" do, when you have the code right there - it takes my-pane's scope and adds a selected property to it.

Comment: Then in that case, how does the scope of my-tabs directive get the selected property for each pane in its scope?

Comment: The scope of my-tabs has a "panes" array. The panes array holds the scope of each pane. Those scopes have a "selected" property.